# How to force MVC views errors to fail project compilation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, compiler-errors

Currently, when I compile, I don't see in compilation windows any errors from cshtml views.

Only if I open views I could see problems red-line underlined. That's it.

I need my compilation to fail if there are errors in views.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open your `csproj` file in notepad and change the `MvcBuildViews` property to true.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- other properties ... -->
    <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
  <!-- the rest of your project file ... -->
```